# Deta Single gang dimmer smart switch

Tags: dimmer-switch, smart-switch

Just planning on replacing my current single switches with a smart switch.

Before calling a sparky, I would like to understand what would be done to not be overcharged.

Is it a matter of connecting the wire from the neutral terminal on the smart switch to that black neutral in the image and then connecting the reds?
Whether the double red supply off to another room needs to be wired or not?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your old switch has a neutral terminal even though it probably doesn't use neutral itself.  That makes things pretty easy.

It looks like you have a solo red hot going to the lamp.

Then you have a double red hot that is a) power coming from source and b) power onward to supply other rooms so they have power too.  You don't need to hook up the latter, but if you don't, the other rooms will be dead.

Then you have a triple neutral which are a) from source, b) neutral onward to supply other rooms, and c) onward to the light.  Again, if you don't hook them all up, stuff will be broken.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I’d assume then the solo red would go to A1, the double red hot/L would go to A, and of course the black goes to N.